# Display Google Map in Specific Place

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios6

I'm new to IOS development and I'm trying to add Google Maps to a sample App. I'm using the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/. Everything is working fine except that the Google Map is taking the entire screen. The code for displaying the Google Map is

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "DemoViewController.h"

@implementation DemoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                          longitude:151.2086
                                                               zoom:6];
  GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
  marker.position = camera.target;
  marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
  marker.animated = YES;

  self.view = mapView;
}

@end
```

The reason why the Google Map is taking the entire screen is because of **self.view = mapView;**. How can I add the Google Map so that it doesn't take the up the full screen.

I tried using a SubView as follow but it is still not working. THe codes are:

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property UIView *myView;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    _myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    [self.view addSubview:_myView];



    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: have you try with new subview and adding `mapView` in that subview?

Comment: @TonyMkenu, I'm using your implementation but its running but not showing the map. You add [self.viewForMap addSubview:_mapView];, but don't you add viewForMap in the main VIew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `self.view = mapView_;` in your `viewDidLoad` method with:

```
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

This adds your mapview to the current view as a subview.

**EDIT**

Try setting the frame of you mapView. Before [self.view addSubview:mapView_]; try:

```
mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];
```

Change 10,10,100,100 for the frame you want for your mapview.

Comment: Do you think I need to call any drawRect method to initiatize the view??

Comment: @Noor never. You do not ever call drawRect. It gets automatically called by the system. You send the message setNeedsDisplay to force a redraw.